# How do I simulate 100% CPU usage?

Tags: cpu, simulate

To simulate 100% CPU usage, I placed an infinite while loop in my code ( while (true) { } ) .
This seemed to spike the CPU usage up to 30% (ordinarily it is 2% for the same program that I run without the while loop).
Why does it not go above 30%? This is a dual core Intel i7 processor. The app is a simple console app running c# code on .net 4.0

```
 private static void SimulateCPUSpike()
 { 
       while(true) { }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPU usage is a percentage of *all* CPU cores.
If your code is only running a single thread, it cannot occupy more than one core.

You need to make a separate thread for each core.  (`Environment.ProcessorCount`)

Answer (score 0):

Dual core cpu, 2 hyperthreads per core.  So you might expect 1 thread at 100% usage to take 25% of the total.  The other 5% is everything else that the system is doing.

Even with 4 threads, you may not get 100% usage, due to scheduling.

The real question is, why do you want 100% usage...are you trying to cook a steak on the CPU?

Comment: Good point , I don't need the 100%, just need it go above 50%  (so not steak, but maybe fry an egg...)

Comment: With modern thermal protection, the CPU would probably throttle its power state (reduce frequency), and even shut off long before your egg becomes even soft boiled.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, this worked from a PowerShell prompt:

```
while(1) {Start-Job {while(1){}}}
```