# How to trick Android to run cpu at max clock speed?

Tags: android, performance

Here is some context. I am working on a 3d game on Android, and have been getting fluctuating FPS which is annoying.

Then I profiled the game and figured out that the processors were not always running at max clock speed. In fact, this was due to the fact that the active (as well as default) governor appeared to be 'interactive', which would try to act smart in that it would adjust clock speed according to current load.

I then rooted my device and set the governor to be 'performance', which locks clock speed at max. As the result the game was running super smooth giving a stable fps of 30.

The issue is that you don't have control, as an application, over what governor to use. That is, you cannot do anything if a player has an un-rooted phone, as it is an OS-level thing anyway. Even if they had their phones rooted, it would be still their, not our, judgement to make in which governor profile to activate.

So my question is, what can we do as developers, on application level, to 'trick' processors so that they are believed to have much work to do, which in fact they do not? The goal is to trick whatever governor to set clock speed at max, or at least at some fixed numbers, so that FPS would not fluctuate and make the game run at a performance that is lacking and below user expectations.

Thanks!

Comment: There is an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549399/how-do-i-simulate-100-cpu-usage

Comment: The reality is you cannot trick the processor as that is outside of developer's control, even if the handset is unrooted, it will be extremely , if not difficult to achieve same. Also, as a developer, you have zero say on those devices whether you like it or not.

Comment: @FatGiant that is a reference to simulating 100% cpu load on desktop, which will induce phone freeze.

Comment: @FatGiant thanks for mentioning that because I forgot to. The solution in the post is about setting up a worker thread on a busy wait. I tried this approach and it wouldn't give reliable results across different devices. Also, it's hard to know in advance how much extra workload we should perform in vain for reaching the balance point.

Comment: @t0mm13b I agree with you on that point, and I know as a fact that the several successful games on the market also shared the same issue. But it's frustrating to accept that 'you simply cannot do anything about it'. lol

Comment: The successful games out there on the market, probably uses Unity3D or similar with the engine in C++ for extra performance, that's about how far it goes.

Comment: @t0mm13b by 'the several' I meant the ones that I profiled.